NuGet package validation during build
I'm trying to build .NET core 8 application with option DOTNET_NUGET_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION set to true. I'm building in OpenShift S2I and using private NuGet repo (Artifactory).
If DOTNET_NUGET_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION=true build takes about 3,5 hours.
If DOTNET_NUGET_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION=false build takes about 3 minutes.
I found article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/the-nuget-org-repository-signing-certificate-will-be-updated-as-soon-as-april-8th-2024/ mentioning that I need to set-up finger print to trusted signer, which I did, but it did not help. In build logs I can see warnings NU3018 and errors NU3034.
NU3018 The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server could not be reached. RevocationStatusUnknown: unable to get certificate CRL
NU3034 This package is signed but not by a trusted signer.

Waringn leads me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/nuget-signed-package-verification where is mentioned, that cenrtification bundle is searched at location
/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/objsign-ca-bundle.pem

I guess I need to add it there, but where I can get it?
I'm not a developer. I'm trying to set OpenShift for our dev guys.
What should I do with NU3034. Do I need some nuget.config vaules from developers?
Thank you.
